# REVTEX author affiliation

Tags: titles, revtex, affiliation

Good morning

I am triing to use RevTex to write an article to APS. I use this code for author affiliation.

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\title{A title} 

\author{Author A}
\affiliation{lab A}
\affiliation{lab C}

\author{Author B1}
\author{Author B2}
\affiliation{lab B}

\author{C}
\affiliation{lab C}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

It gives

[image]

As you can see, author C belongs to lab B instead of lab C.

Actually the true situation I am triing to describe is the following :

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\title{A title} 

\author{Author AC}
\affiliation{lab A}
\affiliation{lab C}

\author{Author A1}
\author{Author A2}
\affiliation{lab A}

\author{C}
\affiliation{lab C}

\author{A3}
\affiliation{lab A}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

and I obtain :

[image]

Here again, affiliation for author A1, A2 C and A3 are wrong.

Do you know how to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussion with @Ger shows that this is a bug in version 4.1g of revtex4-1.  It is fixed in version 4.1r.